# How do I fix this one data pull?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please help, I have one data pull that does not work with collection_select in rails 5.2 and I can not find what I have done incorrectly.

New application using rails 5.2 and ruby 2.6.1, only this code fragment fails to perform.

```
        #---- called by views/myoffer/_form.html.erb
        #---code shown below
module MyoffersHelper

    @my_scosts =    Setmeup.find_by_sql("select (t_is || '--' || description) as shipr, description as cost  from setmeups where active is true and g_is = 'Ship' order by t_is, srby;")

    end
end
      #----- extracted from _form.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: myoffer, local: true) do |form| %>
        # lots of stuff, including 
        # working collection_select 

<div class="field">
<% @my_scosts = "" %>
<% get_scost %>
<%= @myoffer.shipping_quoted %>  # proves shipping_quoted has value
  <%= form.label :shipping_quoted %>
  <%= form.collection_select :shipping_quoted, @my_scosts, :cost, :shipr%>
</div>

        # data as pulled by sql
        FedEx_Large--17.00   | 17.00
         FedEx_Medium--7.00   | 7.00
         FedEx_Small--5.00    | 5.00
         Self_Delivery--1.00  | 1.00
         USPS_2d_Large--9.00  | 9.00
         USPS_2d_Medium--5.00 | 5.00
         USPS_2d_Small--3.00  | 3.00
```

This collection_select display and assigns the correct value, but does not remember the last value selected.  (value does exist as shown by the debug statement above the form.label.)  I have several other find_by_sql collection_select statements that work and do remember last value.  Please help me understand what I have coded incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further experimenting (blundering around like an idiot) I had a thought, what if the value in the dropdown view had to be the same as the data saving to the database?  The data I am using is contained within a text box in the Setmeup table, the shipping_quoted field in the myoffer table is decimal.  I changed the sql query as follows:

```
@myscosts = Setmeup.find_by_sql("select (t_is || '--' || description) as shipr, description::float as cost  from setmeups where active is true and g_is = 'Ship' order by t_is, srby;")
```

and the collection_select now remembers from state change to state change!  Who would have though???